# Dynamic Select Boxes in Angular ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, select, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm an old "backender" and pretty new to Angular and modern frontend programming, but I have to learn...

I have the following problem: There is a list with several different person properties, which are created via ng-repeat from Controller response. The values are editable, but the display control depends on the type of the property. The Gender, for example, needs to be edited via a Select-Box. The options for the select box are obtained from a Rest-Server.
So now the main question: How can I build different Select Boxes for each property?
I tried the following code, which is not working:

```
<section class="contactProperty" ng-repeat="property in contactDetail.properties">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>{{property.message}}</td>
                <td rowspan=2>{{property.value}}
                     
                    <script>
                        var lst = ContactDetailController.getClassification(property.type);
                    </script>
                    
                    <input ng-show="{{property.displaystyle_id}}==1" type="text" ng-model="property.value"/>
                    <select ng-show="{{property.displaystyle_id}}==3" ng-model="property.value">
                        <option ng-repeat="opt in lst" value="{{opt.id}}">{{opt.message}}</option>
                    </select>
                     
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select type="text" ng-model="property.status_id">
                            <option ng-repeat = "status in contactDetail.propertyStatus" value="{{status.id}}">{{status.message}}</option>                                          
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>       
        </table>
    </section>
```

The Controller is defined on the top level element with following code

```
.controller('ContactDetailController',
    ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'ContactDetailService', 
    function ($scope, $rootScope, ContactDetailService) {
        $scope.getContactDetail = function () {
            ContactDetailService.getContactDetail(function(response) {
                if(response.success) {
                    
                    $scope.contactDetail=response;
                } else {
                    
                    $scope.error = response.message;
                }
            });
        };
        
        $scope.getClassifications= function(type) {
            ContactDetailService.getClassifications(type, function(response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    return response;
                }
            });
        };
        
        $scope.getContactDetail();
    }]);
```

And the corresponding service:

```
.factory('ContactDetailService',
    ['$http', '$rootScope', '$location', 
    function ($http, $rootScope, $location) {
         var service = {};
                     
         service.getContactDetail = function(callbackFunc) {
             delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With']; 
            var apiRoot="";
            apiRoot = $rootScope.environments[window.location.host];
            $rootScope.apiRoot=apiRoot;
            var id=$location.search().id;
            $http.get(apiRoot+'/contactdetail?id='+id, {})
            .success(function(response){
                $rootScope.contactDetail=response;
                callbackFunc(response);
            }).error(function(response){
                alert("error"+response.message);
            });

         };
         
         service.getClassifications = function(type, callbackFunc) {
             var apiRoot="";
             apiRoot = $rootScope.environments[window.location.host];
             $http.get(apiRoot+'/classifications?type='+type, {})
             .success(function(response) {
                 callbackFunc(response);
             })
             .error(function(response) {
                 alert("error"+response.message);
             });
         };
         
         
         return service;
    }]);
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: do you want checkboxes or a dropdown?

Comment: I need Dropdowns. Gender is only a example. There are other properties, like position or language, which definitly need dropdowns

Comment: correct if i got it wrong. you have dropdowns which you need to populate with data from REST-server, right? 
in your code i see you have same `ng-model="property.value"` for input and drop-down field. I got confused a little bit there.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The dropdowns are created from the outer ng-repeat, wich renders all properties from contactDetail.properties. But each property needs a different kind of input control. Such as a DatePicker for Birthdays or Dropdowns for Gender, Language and so on.   I'm searching for an generic mechanism to fill the dropdowns by $http.get()-call depending on the value of propertie.displaystyle_id

Comment: you can show/hide fields using `ng-show/ng-hide` or `ng-if` or `ng-switch` depending on your type of variable selected. if this is what you want.

Comment: Thanks maddog. Your hint with ng-switch solved another problem. Now there is only one input element rendered in the DOM instead of all three (2 hidden). I solved the Problem now at the backend. My Json Object now contains all possiblie options for each property.

Comment: All dropdowns are rendered corectly by now, but there is still one Problem left: it seems that angular set the value for 'ng-model="property.value' befor rendering the options. So the dropdown does shows the first entry instead of the one corresponding to the value...

Comment: Sorry did not get the last problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can show/hide fields using `ng-show/ng-hide` or `ng-if` or `ng-switch` depending on your type of variable selected. if this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain more precisley:

This is a part of my incomming Json from the Backend:

```
"properties": [
        {
            "id": 8,
            "type_id": 25,
            "status_id": 13,
            "contact_id": 4,
            "value": "27",
            "create_date": null,
            "update_date": null,
            "guikey": "gui.gender",
            "message": "Geschlecht",
            "displaystyle_id": 3,
            "queryparam": "9",
            "options": [
                {
                    "id": 26,
                    "type": 9,
                    "guikey": "gui.male",
                    "language": "de",
                    "message": "Männlich",
                    "displaystyle_id": 0
                },
                {
                    "id": 27,
                    "type": 9,
                    "guikey": "gui.female",
                    "language": "de",
                    "message": "Weiblich",
                    "displaystyle_id": 0
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
```

It is rendered by following code:

```
<section class="contactProperty" ng-repeat="property in contactDetail.properties">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{property.message}}</td>
                    <td rowspan=2 ng-switch on="property.displaystyle_id">{{property.value}}
                        <input ng-switch-when="1" type="text" ng-model="property.value"/>
                        <input ng-switch-when="2" type="date" ng-model="property.value"/>
                        <select ng-switch-when="3" ng-model="property.value">
                            <option ng-repeat="opt in property.options" value="{{opt.id}}">{{opt.message}}</option>
                        </select>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{property.status_id}}
                        <select type="text" ng-model="property.status_id">
                                <option ng-repeat = "status in contactDetail.propertyStatus" value="{{status.id}}">{{status.message}}</option>                                          
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>       
            </table>
        </section>
```

The resulting HTML contains a Select box as expacted:

```
<section class="contactProperty ng-scope" ng-repeat="property in contactDetail.properties">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="ng-binding">Geschlecht</td>
<td class="ng-binding" on="property.displaystyle_id" ng-switch="" rowspan="2">
27
<select class="ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="property.value" ng-switch-when="3">
<option class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="26" ng-repeat="opt in property.options">Männlich</option>
<option class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="27" ng-repeat="opt in property.options">Weiblich</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</section>
```

But the Browser displays the Value "Männlich" in this example, but I expected to see "Weiblich" because the property.value 27 is passed from the json. I just show the value for debug as {{property.value}} and it shows 27, which is correct. I don't understand why the dropdown still showing the first entry (26/Männlich) in this case...

Comment: i guess you need to tell `ng-repeat` to track by `property.value` . There is `track by` property for `ng-repeat`. 
give me sometime. need to check this one.